# I need to schedule a job to run once at startup on Windows 2016 without a user logon

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm automating builds of windows servers in AWS (via packer and terraform).  I have a userdata script that changes the hostname when host is started and reboots after.
My problem is that, after the system reboots, I need a software installation to happen (because it relies on the changed name.)

I've tried something like this:

```
$RunOnceKey = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
set-itemproperty $RunOnceKey "NextRun" ('C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -executionPolicy Unrestricted -File ' + "C:\mydir\after-boot\install_mysoftware.ps1")
```

The problem with this is that it only runs after a user login, which is unacceptable.
So I read about RunServiceOnce, but when I try to use that in place of RunOnce, I get an error:

```
set-itemproperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Administrator\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce' 
because it does not exist
```

How can I ensure my program runs once on system boot without waiting for a user login? Point/click won't work. I need a powershell solution to set this up.

Comment: Why could you not make this into a scheduled task to run on reboot? or you can switch to workflows to deal the same. Have a look at [THIS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-workflows-restarting-the-computer/) also

Comment: Yes, good idea and I looked at that initially but workflows do not work from userdata in AWS.  Thanks for reminder though, i'll keep that in mind for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is windows server, you can also schedule task in Windows Task Scheduler.

EXAMPLE:

```
$destination = "C:\Windows\Tasks\InstallSoftware.ps1"

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument $destination

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RemoveAppLogs' -TaskPath '\CustomTasks\' -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Description 'The task will run script to install software.' -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this !